# SQL, specific group by

Tags: sql, pivot

I have this table:

[image]

and I want to have sth like this:

[image]

where I have counted salary for  each type. I know that I should use group by, but it gives me as a result row under row, and I want to have this in separate columns. I'm using SQL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use conditional aggregation:

```
select count(*),
       sum(case when type = 'A' then salary end) as salary_a,
       sum(case when type = 'B' then salary end) as salary_b,
       sum(case when type = 'C' then salary end) as salary_c
from t;
```